# Displaying inputs using methods in java

Tags: java

I copied this code in a book I found in the internet about Data Structures and Algorithm in Java. This is the code:

```
//GameEntry Class

public class GameEntry
{
    protected String name;
    protected int score;

    public GameEntry(String n, int s) {
         name = n;
         score = s;
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }

    public int getScore() { return score; }

    public String toString() {
         return "(" + name + ", " + score + ")";
    }
}

//Scores Class

public class Scores
{
     public static final int maxEntries = 10;
     protected int numEntries;
     protected GameEntry[] entries;

     public Scores(){
          entries = new GameEntry[maxEntries];
          numEntries = 3;
     }

     public String toString() {
          String s = "[";
          for(int i=0; i<numEntries; i++) {
                if(i > 0) {
                s = s + ", ";          
                }
                s = s + entries[i];
          }
          return s + "]";
     }

     public static void main(String[] args){
          Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
          Scores s = new Scores();

          for(int i=0; i<s.numEntries; i++){
                System.out.print("Enter Name: ");
                String nm = input.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Enter Score: ");
                int sc = input.nextInt();
                input.nextLine();
                s.entries[i] = new GameEntry(nm, sc);

               System.out.println(s.toString());
          }
     }
}
```

This runs well like what it said in the book. It outputs:

```
//just an example input
[(John, 89), (Peter, 90), (Matthew, 90)]
```

What I don't understand is how did the names inside the parenthesis which is made in the GameEntry Class inside its toString() method (John, 89) is being outputted and yet what I written inside the System.out.println(s.toString); in Scores Class only pertains to the toString method in its own class?

I am expecting that the brackets in the toString() method in the Scores Class will be outputting only the brackets "[]" for it is the only one that I called in the main method... Can anyone please explain this to me how did this happened? I am little bit new in Java Data Structures.

Another thing I try to do this in a different sample program following the concept of what I see in the book..

This my codes:

```
//FirstClass

public class FirstClass
{
    protected String name;
    protected int age;

    protected FirstClass(String n, int a) {
         name = n;
         age = a;
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }

    public int getAge() { return age; }

    public String printData() {
           return "My name is: " + name + ", I am " + age + " years old";
    }
}

//Second Class

import java.util.Scanner;

public class SecondClass
{
    protected FirstClass f;
    private static String nm;
    private static int ag;

    public SecondClass() {
        f = new FirstClass(nm, ag);
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "(" + f + ")";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        SecondClass s = new SecondClass();

        System.out.print("Enter Name: ");
        nm = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter Age: ");
        ag = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();
        s.f = new FirstClass(nm, ag);
        System.out.println(s.toString());
    }
}

//Sample Input
Enter Name: John
Enter Age: 16
```

The output of this is:

```
(FirstClass@7cc7b1d2)
```

What I am expecting is:

```
("My name: is John, I am 16 years old")
```

What is my error in this???

Comment: Please don't link to code, especially not to images of code. Put all relevant code as text in your question.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel done editing...

Comment: You did not override `toString()` in `firstClass`...

Comment: @MarkRotteveel it's working well now, but I am still a little confused. I changed the toString() method name in SecondClass to showData() but it is still working well. How come that I make them different again it is still working? Is the word toString as a method a special thing in java??? Sorry I am still new to java and there are many basic things I haven't learned yet...

Comment: @MarkRotteveel in the FirstClass I changed the toString() method to printData again and in SecondClass I changed the toString() method to printData as well and now output became wrong again... Is there really something special to the toString as a method name in java??

Comment: Yes, `toString()` is special, it is invoked by `System.out.println(Object)`, and it is automatically invoked when you concatenate an object to a string.